# python3.3 manage.py syncdb syntax error

Tags: python, django, syntax-error, syncdb

Very new to Django - I'm trying to get a site set up on Webfaction using their guide. http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/getting-started.html

I've updated settings.py as instructed but I'm getting a syntax error in my settings.py file. I've tried going through and making sure there are no tabs and just spaces.

Here's the error message:

```
python3.3 manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/bstolte/webapps/mo_detector/lib/python3.3/django/core/management/__init__.py",    line 399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/bstolte/webapps/mo_detector/lib/python3.3/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/bstolte/webapps/mo_detector/lib/python3.3/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
commands = get_commands()
File "/home/bstolte/webapps/mo_detector/lib/python3.3/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/home/bstolte/webapps/mo_detector/lib/python3.3/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/home/bstolte/webapps/mo_detector/lib/python3.3/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/home/bstolte/webapps/mo_detector/lib/python3.3/django/conf/__init__.py", line 128, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1586, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1567, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1534, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1024, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1005, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 855, in _load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 982, in get_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/bstolte/webapps/mo_detector/mo_detector/mo_detector/settings.py", line 35
INSTALLED_APPS = (
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas on why it's failing at INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Can you show the settings.py file ?

Comment: there might be `syntaxerror`, ie you might missing `bracket` or `comma` above the line containing `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you get a syntax error like that that's pointing at something you don't see any error with, it means there's an unclosed bracket, indentation block or other item preceding that in the file.  The settings.py file follows normal Python syntax rules like any other .py file, so look for stuff preceding that line that might cause the parser to choke.

Comment: Right on - thanks so much. I had an unclosed bracket... ugh.  Thanks again.